Parsing quicktime MOOV atoms to mp4 DASH MOOV atoms
I am exploring Kaltura nginx vod module to get DASH playback which having single audio and video quicktime file(.mov).
But Playback is failing and player is not even requesting m4s segments with below error once it makes init-a1-x3.mp4 request.
Video Element Error: MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED (CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED: RunSegmentParserLoop: stream parsing failed. append_window_start=0 append_window_end=146.11)
Upon reviewing MOOV ATOMS in audio I am observing qt_version, wave, frma etc using mp4dump from bento. So in order to fix this used the below ffmpeg command just to parse the quicktime MOOV atoms to mp4 MOOV atoms on DASH output init mp4 file.
ffmpeg -v debug -i init-a1-x3.mp4 -c copy -f mp4 -movflags +dash -movie_timescale 9000  init-ffmpeg.mp4 -y

After replacing the init-a1-x3.mp4 with init-ffmpeg.mp4 now player not giving error but observed AV sync issues.
So again checked the MOOV atoms using bento mp4dump but timescale in mdhd got changed to different value with the input file. So please let me know any tool which can parse the only MOOV atoms of quicktime to proper DASH mp4 format.
Please let me know if any further more info is required or sample file.
